# How to collect the compiled modules?

Tags: python, shared-libraries

For deployment I would like to build a base image for a PC. Therefore I would need a build script to build the system from the base image. To the base image I would like to install several python modules. But the base image shouldn't contain the development/build tools (e.g. python-dev).

Therefore my plan is to

1. Install the development/build tools
2. Use pip install to install the item (e.g. paramiko)
3. Collect the compiled and installed modules, and then put the compiled module in somewhere
4. In the build script it will copy the pre-compiled python modules into the system

In short the sourcecode is being obtained and is being compiled. But how can I copy out the compiled module and deploy it to another platform?

Thanks in advance